# how to create list of inner members using java 8 lambda?

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8

I have this class:

```
Class A
{
    List<B> B
}


Class B {
    List<C> c
}
```

given an instance of `A` how can I use java lambada to create a list of all inner `c`?

I have tried:

```
    List<Alternative> alternatives = e2EResult.completeRoutingResponses.stream().map(item -> {
        return item.alternatives }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Please post a code that is matching your class. Your class name is not matching to what you've tried..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it with `flatMap` :

```
List<Alternative> alternatives = 
    e2EResult.completeRoutingResponses.stream()
                                      .flatMap(item -> item.alternatives.stream())
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @EladBenda Your solution produces a `List<List<Alternative>>` instead of a `List<Alternative>`.